# How to replace the button positions by dragging one button on to another button in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uibutton

I am having two UIButtons(button1 and button2) of two different frames, the thing is  I want to  drag the button2 on to the button1 so that the button2 is repositioned to button1 position, and button2 should occupy button1 position.

Guy's I need ur help and ideas how can I do with it.

Thanks to all,
Monish

Comment: Which parts of the problem have you figured out? Have you been able to do the click and drag part? Or are you just trying to figure out how to switch the position of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect rect = btn.frame;
btn.frame = btn2.frame;
btn2.frame = rect;
```

If you want to animate this, start with reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a)

Is it what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the button's x-axis in frame and use animations to show it as its moving (if you want) accordingly.

```
[buttonOutletName setFrame:CGRectMake(old_xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height)];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
[buttonOutletName setFrame:CGRectMake(new_xCoordinate, yCoordinate, width, height)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If helpful please mark :)